# Py2exe EOF error when compiling

Tags: python, py2exe

Below is a simple file rename program that runs and works great, when launching from Python. Whenever I try compiling this program into a single .exe it won't launch and gives this error: File "UserInputRenameReplace.py", line 12, in  EOFError: EOF when reading line.

What could this error mean, and why does it run fine in Python but not Py2exe?

```
import os 

path = os.getcwd() #Working/active directory 

filenames = os.listdir(path) 

print "**Rename Active Directory File(s)**\n" 

cur_Name = raw_input("Current Name: ") 

new_Name = raw_input("New Name: ")

for filename in filenames: 
os.rename(os.path.join(path, filename), os.path.join(path, filename.replace(cur_Name, new_Name)))
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `setup.py` make sure you are specifying `console=['myscript.py']` and not `windows=['myscript.py']`. The "EOF when reading line" error can result from `stdin` being closed.